# Is there a better way other than this.$forceUpdate() to update elements?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, element-ui

I am using vueJS to handle a function which reloads my  element.

We have our HTML elements here, a dropdown list to display the option

```
<el-select v-model="row.display_name_uuid">
  <el-option v-for="(item, i) in displayNameList" 
           :key="i" :value="item.uuid" 
           :label="item.display_name">
   </el-option>
</el-select>
```

Then we have our method here list is our array data and DisplayNameList contains the dropdown list's select options.

the flow is we create a new data by createDisplayNameExclusive(), then we calls the refreshDIsplayList() to reload the displayname list, then we trigger this.getExclusiceUuid() to refresh the this.list

```
createDisplayNameExclusive(data).then(res => {
                if (res.status_code == 200) {
                    this.$message({
                        message: 'Created',
                        type: 'success'
                    })
                    this.dialogFormVisible = false
                    
                    data.key = this.form.key
                    
                    this.$parent. refreshDisplayNameList(data, res.content.data)
                    this.$parent.getExclusiceUuid(data, res.content.data)

                    this.$forceUpdate()
                    
                } else {
                    this.$message({
                        message: res.content.message,
                        type: 'warning'
                    })
                }
            }).catch(e => {
                this.loading = false
            })
        },

    async refreshDisplayNameList(e, updated_data) {

        let displayNameCombine = []
                let data = {
                    ledgerType: 'DisplayName'
                }
                
            let res = await getList(data);
        if (res && res.status_code == 200) {
            this.displayNameList = displayNameCombine;
        }
}


getExclusiceUuid (data, val) {
              this.refreshDisplayNameList() // refresh the newly added data

                this.list.forEach((item, index) => { //loop until key paired 
                    if (item.key == data.key) {
                        let obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item))

                        this.list.splice(index, 1)//we try to remove it first         

                        this.displayNameList = [...this.displayNameList]
            
                        this.list = [...this.list]
                        
                        this.$forceUpdate()

                        obj.display_name_uuid = val

                        this.list.splice(index, 0, obj) //then we add it back here to try to force update

                        this.$forceUpdate()
                    }
                })
            },
```

After we update the Display Name List content we would also like to update the contain within the select box, but it doesn't seem like it updates normally even we confirm the function runs after his.refreshDisplayNameList(), the select element doesn't seem to refresh even we use this.list.splice(index, 1)  remove it and recreate.

and
[image]

Comment: what is the purpose of this `getExclusiceUuid` function? how/where is it being used? what does `this.refreshDisplayNameList()` do? how/where are `this.list` and `this.displayNameList` declared? the manual for `$forceUpdate()` states - *The only cases where you may need it is when you have explicitly created non-reactive component state using advanced reactivity APIs.* - but you've shown absolutely nothing

Comment: It isn't needed in such case at all. If data isn't updated in a view, probably you did something wrong. Like "key" is supposed to prevent unwanted rerenders, and you use an index for a key, which is generally discouraged exactly because this can lead to the situation you describe. Since you already have unique id, use it instead

Comment: i have updated the detail, please see if this makes more sense

Comment: this.$parent. refreshDisplayNameList without space ?

Comment: As @EstusFlask suggested, vue will handle this update automatically if you change from `:key="i"` to something that's specific to each particular item, for example: `:key="item.uuid"`